# How to create element of a 3rd party component in React using ES5 syntax?

Tags: reactjs

I am using React version 15.1.0. I want to use medium-draft editor from https://github.com/brijeshb42/medium-draft. I am trying to create an element but I get an error.

```
var React = require('react')
var MediumDraftEditor = require('medium-draft');

 var EmailTemplateContent = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <MediumDraftEditor/>;

   },
```

});

```
And, in some component I am calling this component
<EmailTemplateContent/>
```

I am getting following errors

```
Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of  `EmailTemplateContent`.
http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/bundles/main-0a3cbca2a704a676c74d.js
Line 1127

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. Check the render method of `EmailTemplateContent`.
```

Comment: The docs state to use `import Editor from 'medium-draft'` which is because medium-draft exposes MediumDraftEditor as just Editor in the index.js file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs are written in ES2015 syntax. The docs show to grab components from the 'medium-draft' package like this:

```
import {
  Editor,
  createEditorState,
} from 'medium-draft';
```

The ES5 equivalent will look like this:

```
var Editor = require('medium-draft').Editor;
var createEditorState = require('medium-draft').createEditorState;
```